# Transformation of the limits in an integral (From Probability)

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

[image]

Hello, I am solving the problem above and am close to the solution but I have a small wall that I cannot pass through.

My work is the following.

$$E \left[e^{t \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)} \right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)} f(x) dx$$

$$= e^{ \frac{-\mu t}{\sigma} } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{tx}{\sigma} } f(x) dx$$

$$= e^{ \frac{-\mu t}{\sigma} } M \left[\frac{t}{\sigma}\right]$$

But I am not comfortable with why the limit of $t$ becomes $-h\sigma < t < h\sigma$.

I know that if $$\int_{-h}^{h} e^{tx} f(x) dx = M[t]$$
then
$$\int_{-h \sigma}^{h \sigma} e^{\frac{tx}{\sigma} } f(x) dx = M\left[\frac{t}{\sigma}\right]$$
from transformation of the variables but I am not confident...

May I have some help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) avoid writing integrals altogether because you don't know if the random variable $X$ has a density.

Imitating your steps yields
$$E e^{t(X-\mu)/\sigma)} = e^{-t \mu / \sigma} E[e^{(t/\sigma)X}] = e^{-t \mu / \sigma} M(t/\sigma)$$
as long as $M(t/\sigma)$ is defined. Since $M(\cdot)$ is only defined on the interval $(-h, h)$, we must have $-h < t/\sigma < h$.

Comment: I do not know why I did not notice that... Thank you very much!